# Sending data from a mobile flex application to a windows server running FMS and SOAP/IIS

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile

I have an app that records the mic using FMS 3. I am modifying this to work on a mobile environment however that doesn't let you stream the mic in the same way. 
You normally do it by attaching a mic to netstream.

```
out_ns.attachAudio(mic);
out_ns.publish(_settings.streamUid, "record");
```

I now record the speech to a buffer, and have to send it to the web service somehow. Is it possible to use a net stream to send a buffer/array? I havn't managed to get it working.

I have tried sending data like you are supposed to be able to do to send headers, but the file doesn't get created on the server.
    var metaData:Object = new Object();
    metaData.title = "myStream";
    metaData.width = 400;
    metaData.height = 200;
    out_ns.send("@setDataFrame", "onMetaData", metaData);
    out_ns.publish("mystream");

Is it possible to stream a buffer without attaching a mic or anything?
If not then what is the best way to send the data to an IIS server? We already send small amounts of data using SOAP.

Is this a possibility?
[Upload arbitrary data in HTTP Post in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507913/upload-arbitrary-data-in-http-post-in-flex)

Yes that is a possibility however the system is already set up for streaming, so I want to keep doing that. It will also mean less lag as the data can be posted as it is recorded.
Can you post simple example code that will post something to a server running FMS 3 with mobile AIR?

Comment: You should be able to send over some simple objects.  What problems are you having?  can you show more of the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS, then I would highly recommend checking out WebORB.Net or FlourineFX, personally I find WebORB freaking amazing.

http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=42